# how to uninstall a desktop gadget/widget in w7

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

I've installed this widget called magic folder. But it crashes often how do I uninstall it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click desktop and click Gadgets
2. Select the gadget and right click, **Remove**

That should be all :)